# NHibernate inner Join an Oracle and Sql Server Database

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, oracle, nhibernate

I am building an object from multiple datasources. Does anyone know whether this is possible in NHibernate and how. I should mention that one source is SQL the other ORACLE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are able to create a database link on the Oracle database, NHibernate should be able to effectively pick up the objects from either database. I have used a similar pattern, although connecting to [**two instances of Oracle**](http://mikehadlow.blogspot.com/2008/10/mapping-entities-to-multiple-databases.html).